# Should I always use ObservedObject for child views of parent view when parent view use StateObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a main view as ContentView which I am using a StateObject like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var myClass: MyClass = MyClass.shared
    var body: some View {
        // Other views needs myClass
        ChildView(myClass: myClass)
        // Other views needs myClass
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myClass: MyClass
    var body: some View {
        // Other views
        EmptyView()
        // Other views
    }
}

class MyClass: ObservableObject {
    static let shared: MyClass = MyClass()
}
```

As you can see I used ObservedObject for child view, and i think the codes are political correct, how ever I could simply use StateObject for ObservedObject like this:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject var myClass: MyClass = MyClass.shared
    var body: some View {
        // Other views
        EmptyView()
        // Other views
    }
}
```

And the codes would also work, i want to know is it a must that we should respect to parent and use ObservedObject or what is pro and cons if I used StateObject?

Comment: The difference between StateObject and ObservedObject is lifecycle management. ObservedObject doesn’t have the ability to preserve an item when a view gets reloaded. So your question should be who should determine the life of an object? A singleton doesn’t need lifecycle management. Do you need that object to be alive for as long as the app is alive? Or as long as the View is alive? There are very few things that need to stay alive as long as the app is alive.

Comment: I don´t get your comment, my ContentView would be never killed and it would be alive until app is alive, but child view would be used and killed when child view done it`s job.

Comment: StateObject is redundant and pointless with a singleton. Singletons are generally considered to not be good practice there are many arguments about the subject online.

Comment: There is also another level to this. If you don't need the view to react to the `ObservableObject` you don't need to use `@ObservedObject` in the view, i.e. you just want to call a function on the class, but don't need a view update as. result. The same goes for the initial instantiation. If that view does not need to react to the `ObservableObject`, it can actually be instantiated as `@State`. The concern as to how to instantiate it comes down to your App's lifecycle.